# Cast between String and Classname

Tags: ruby, string, class, constants

I have a string, containing an Class name. It is, for example, a string containing "Article". That string came up from the params[]. What should I do to work with this string as if it was a class name? For instance, I want to do:

```
Article.all
```

and so on.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is better than **eval** as you are evaluating **params** hash that might be manipulated by the user and could contain harmful actions. As a general rule: **Never evaluate user input directly, that's a big security hole.**

```
# Monkey patch for String class
    class String
      def to_class
        klass = Kernel.const_get(self)
        klass.is_a?(Class) ? klass : nil
      rescue NameError
        nil
      end
    end

# Examples
"Fixnum".to_class #=> Fixnum
"Something".to_class #=> nil
```

**Update - a better version that works with namespaces:**

```
 # Monkey patch for String class
    class String
      def to_class
        chain = self.split "::"
        klass = Kernel
        chain.each do |klass_string|
          klass = klass.const_get klass_string
        end
        klass.is_a?(Class) ? klass : nil
      rescue NameError
        nil
      end
    end
```

Comment: This won't won't work with namespaced classes, like `MyModule::MyClass`. For that you'd have to split on "::" and then, for example, use inject with const_get.

Comment: Good point. I added the active_support def, which is much more in line with your (better) suggestion.

Comment: I have added a new post regarding it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448670/ruby-stringtoclass

Comment: For now, the code you posted is a bit of "dark materia" for me :P Great thanks anyway!

Comment: It's a more general solution as a response to sepp2k's note regarding namespaces like MyModule::MyClass

Answer (score 3):

```
class Abc
end #=> nil
klass = eval("Abc") #=> Abc
klass.new #=> #<Abc:0x37643e8>
```

Assumes there really is a class with the name provided...

In ActiveSupport, there was [String#constantize](http://apidock.com/rails/Inflector/constantize), which did the same thing, but I believe it's deprecated after 2.1.

EDIT: this is the implementation of constantize from ActiveSupport 2.1.2:

```
  def constantize(camel_cased_word)
    names = camel_cased_word.split('::')
    names.shift if names.empty? || names.first.empty?

    constant = Object
    names.each do |name|
      constant = constant.const_defined?(name) ? constant.const_get(name) : constant.const_missing(name)
    end
    constant
  end
```

Comment: It's a bit dangerous to use eval for params cause it might contain harmful code. I don't recommend this solutions

Comment: @khelll: Since your answer got accepted, it's now "your solution above"!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understand your intention correctly. Here I assume `all` is an Class method of `Article` and `all` return an array of articles.

```
class Article
    def self.all
       ["Peopleware" , "The Mythical Man-Month"]
    end

end

s = "Article"
all_of_article = []
eval("all_of_article = #{s + ".all"}")
puts all_of_article.inspect  # ["Peopleware", "The Mythical Man-Month"]
```