# Get a class by name in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Having a string with the module and name of a class, like:

```
"Admin::MetaDatasController"
```

how do I get the actual class?

The following code works if there's no module:

```
Kernel.const_get("MetaDatasController")
```

but it breaks with the module:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > Kernel.const_get("Admin::MetaDatasController")
NameError: wrong constant name Admin::MetaDatasController
        from (irb):34:in `const_get'
        from (irb):34
ruby-1.8.7-p174 >
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448670/ruby-stringto-class

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you want something simple that handles just your special case you can write

```
Object.const_get("Admin").const_get("MetaDatasController")
```

But if you want something more general, split the string on `::` and resolve the names one after the other:

```
def class_from_string(str)
  str.split('::').inject(Object) do |mod, class_name|
    mod.const_get(class_name)
  end
end

the_class = class_from_string("Admin::MetaDatasController")
```

On the first iteration `Object` is asked for the constant `Admin` and returns the `Admin` module or class, then on the second iteration that module or class is asked for the constant `MetaDatasController`, and returns that class. Since there are no more components that class is returned from the method (if there had been more components it would have iterated until it found the last).

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using `Kernel` as the receiver? a Top-level constant is defined on `Object` not on `Kernel`.

Comment: The OP used it, and I didn't stop to look up which might be the actual module that defined top level constants. I've changed it.

Answer (score 50):

ActiveSupport provides a method called constantize, which will do this. If you are on Rails, which I assume you are based on the name of your constant, then you already have ActiveSupport loaded.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string'

class Admin
  class MetaDatasController
  end
end

"Admin::MetaDatasController".constantize # => Admin::MetaDatasController
```

To see how the method is implemented, check out https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/85c2141fe3d7edb636a0b5e1d203f05c70db39dc/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L230-L253

Comment: When adding a link to a github file, press y to get a direct link to that specific commit.

Comment: You can also use `ActiveSupport::Inflector#constantize` which doesn't require you to require the entire String core extension.

Answer (score 24):

In Ruby 2.x, you can just do this:

```
Object.const_get('Admin::MetaDatasController')
=> Admin::MetaDatasController
```

Comment: Note that if you do not know if the constant exists, you can either `Object.const_get(str) rescue nil` or `Object.const_defined?(str) && Object.const_get(str)`

Answer (score 1):

i could be way off-base, but wouldn't eval return the class?

```
eval("Admin::MetaDatasController")
```

so `eval("Admin::MetaDatasController").new` would be the same as `Admin::MetaDatasController.new`

Comment: Yeah, but it comes with a lot of baggage. Namely, security and speed. A good general rule is to avoid cavalier use of eval. Also, be careful who you suggest this around, or you could find yourself being torched at the stake for fraternizing with evil (it tends to be a touchy subject).

Comment: :-) got it. eval = evil with a spelling mistake.