# create instances dynamically, from class name

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a Ruby program that generates files that contain a Module definition :

```
 # try.rb
 module Test
  class F1
   def initialize arg
     @arg=arg
   end
  end
 end
```

Now, I'd like the **same program** to create instances of F1.

What is the right idiom to do that ?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163641/get-a-class-by-name-in-ruby

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`load` or `require` the file:

```
load 'path/to/try.rb'
```

then you can use `Object.const_get` to get a reference to the class object, and use that to create an instance:

```
cls = Object.const_get('Test').const_get('F1')
obj = cls.new('foo')
```

Comment: You could also shorten that to `Object.const_get('Test::F1')`