# Eval in a module, but the class is not part of the module

Tags: ruby, module, eval

I have a module `Database`. In this module, `eval("MyClass")` returns `Database::MyClass is inexistent`. But I want it to be evaluated outside of the `Database`module. Who knows how this is to be done?

Comment: Have you tried `eval("::MyClass")`? And why do you use `eval` at all? Show some code.

Comment: `eval("::MyClass")` was the solution, thanks! if you make it a whole comment, I can accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try specifying global scope explicitly then:

```
eval('::MyClass')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access a class by its name contained in a string, it might be a better choice to use Kernel.const_get. See this stack overflow post for more info:[Get a class by name in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163641/get-a-class-by-name-in-ruby)