# Generate dynamic classes and instances methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to generate complete classes in Ruby, that extend other classes. For example, I have my function:

```
def generator(classname, methodname, ModelClass)
  # make the class
  # now make the instance method on the class
end
```

and calling it generates a class like below:

```
generator 'ArticlesController' 'save' 'Article'

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def save 
    @generated_params = # generate params from Article
    @item = Article.new(@generated_params)
    @item.save
  end
end
```

except that I can make new classes based on some input.

Comment: Define "fast". Define "many". Can you give a better example?

Comment: updated it to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case code will be like this:

```
def generator(classname, methodname, arbitrary_class = ArbitraryClass)
  klass = Class.new(Parent) do
    define_method(methodname) do |*args, &block|
      @generated_params = # generate params from method_arg
      @item = arbitrary_class.new(@generated_params)
      @item.save
    end
  end
  Object.const_set classname, klass
end
```

This code do three things:

1. creates an anonymous class
2. adds a method to the new class
3. associate the new class with `classname` constant

Also this code does not receive a parent class for the generated class, I hope it will be easy to add. The generated method may receive any number of argument, they available through `args`.

**Update:** I will add here a way how to receive a class constant from a string for `arbitrary_class`:

```
"Article".constantize # Article
```

Comment: Also this code expects to receive `arbitrary_class` as a constant, not as a string. A call should be like `generator 'ArticlesController', 'save', Article`. Notice that the last argument is not a string here.

Comment: awesome. I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163641/get-a-class-by-name-in-ruby for that anyway. Thanks Ilya

Comment: uh oh it didnt work: `NoMethodError: undefined method `constantize' for "ClassName":String`

Comment: `constantize` comes from Rails and it does not work in plain Ruby (without Rails). Are you sure you are trying in Rails environment?