# Adding a method to several classes in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to add a method to several classes. But I am missing some thing that I don't know how to call it so I can't search for it

I want to do something like

```
["Class1", "Class2"].each do |klass|
 class klass.constantize
  def my_new_method
   ....
  end
 end
end
```

obviously the code doesn't work, but you get the point. How do I make klass be a class name so I can declare the method?

Comment: I think these answers will be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163641/get-a-class-by-name-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`const_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-const_get) and [`class_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-class_eval):

```
class A; 
  def a; 
    puts :a; 
  end; 
end
Kernel.const_get("A").class_eval { def b; puts :b; end  }

pry(main)> A.new.b
b
=> nil
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding the functionality to several classes is usually made with mixins. [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend) is your friend here. That way one gets an ability to call `super` if the method *overrides* the existing one from the extended class.

```
["Class1", "Class2"].each do |klass|
  Kernel.const_get(klass).prepend(Module.new do
    def my_new_method
      ....
    end
  end)
end
```

---

Or, alternatively, you might declare this module upfront and call `prepend` passing a module name there.

```
Mixin =
  Module.new do
    def my_new_method
      ....
    end
  end

["Class1", "Class2"].each do |klass|
  Kernel.const_get(klass).prepend(Mixin)
end
```

---

Or,

```
module Mixin
  def my_new_method
    ....
  end
end

["Class1", "Class2"].each do |klass|
  Kernel.const_get(klass).prepend(Mixin)
end
```