# How do I get class-object from string "A::B::C" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, object

The following example fails

```
class A
  class B
  end
end
p Object.const_get 'A' # => A
p Object.const_get 'A::B' # => NameError: wrong constant name A::B
```

---

**UPDATE**

Questions about the topic asked earlier:

1. [Cast between String and Classname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448293/cast-between-string-and-classname)
2. [Ruby String#to_class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448670/ruby-stringto-class)
3. [Get a class by name in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163641/get-a-class-by-name-in-ruby)

The last one [gives a nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163641/get-a-class-by-name-in-ruby/3163713#3163713) which can be evolved into

```
class String
  def to_class
    self.split('::').inject(Object) do |mod, class_name|
      mod.const_get(class_name)
    end
  end
end

class A
  class B
  end
end
p "A::B".to_class # => A::B
```

Comment: What happens if I'd like to declare use the `to_class` method and assign its value to a `CONSTANT` within a `class`, e.g. `class A  begin MY_CONST = "SomeOtherClass".to_class end` ? I get uninitialized constant if calling outside `initialize` for instance. `class_eval`, what could I try? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to manually "parse" the colons yourself and call `const_get` on the parent module/class:

```
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > class A
ruby-1.9.1-p378 ?>  class B
ruby-1.9.1-p378 ?>    end
ruby-1.9.1-p378 ?>  end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > A.const_get 'B'
 => A::B
```

Someone has written a [`qualified_const_get`](http://redcorundum.blogspot.com/2006/05/kernelqualifiedconstget.html) that may be of interest.

Answer (score 6):

Here is Rails' `constantize` method:

```
def constantize(camel_cased_word)
  names = camel_cased_word.split('::')
  names.shift if names.empty? || names.first.empty?

  constant = Object
  names.each do |name|
    constant = constant.const_defined?(name) ? constant.const_get(name) : constant.const_missing(name)
  end
  constant
end
```

See, it starts at the `Object` on top of it all, then uses each name in between the double semicolons as a stepping stone to get to the constant you want.

Answer (score 0):

Extlib provides a `full_const_get` method, which does just this.

http://github.com/datamapper/extlib/blob/master/lib/extlib/object.rb#L67

You could either include extlib, or copy this implementation and use it yourself (assuming the licensing is compatible with whatever you're using it for)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with eval also which works in some cases where const_get won't.
There's a good article on this here:
http://blog.sidu.in/2008/02/loading-classes-from-strings-in-ruby.html#.T8j88HlYtXc