# How to get a class from a String?

Tags: ruby, string, class, constants

I'd like to index a hash with a Class (not a symbol !), like the following

```
irb(main):015:0> class Key ;end
=> nil
irb(main):016:0> h={Key => "ok"}
=> {Key=>"ok"}
```

Good.
Then, given the name of the Class, as a string, I want the get the element :

```
irb(main):017:0> str="Key"
=> "Key"
irb(main):018:0> h[str]
=> nil
```

But (as shown above) this fails (of course).

So my question : how can I transform a String to the actual Class ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast between String and Classname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448293/cast-between-string-and-classname)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Kernel#const_get`:

```
str = "Key"
k = Kernel.const_get(str)
val = h[k]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Rails then you'll find ActiveSupport's "constantize" to do what you want.

```
"String".constantize
=> String
```

But you can do something similar.

```
Object.const_get("String")
=> String
```

You can even define this on string

```
class String
  def constantize
    Object.const_get(self)
  end
end
```

note: try to avoid doing "eval" unless you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (you probably don't want to use `eval`):

```
>> class Key ;end #=> nil
>> h={Key => "ok"} #=> {Key=>"ok"}
>> str="Key" #=> "Key"
>> h[Kernel.const_get(str)] #=> "ok"
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use `h[eval(str)]`.  More information on [eval in the Ruby 1.9.3 docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Binding.html#method-i-eval)

I should add this is a sharp knife, do not cut yourself with this technique.  You want to make sure that the string you are eval'ing cannot contain any malicious code.

Comment: I don't think we should advise people to use `eval` unless its necessary. In this case its definitely not necessary.

Comment: Fair criticism, there are other better ways for this problem.